# check mulitple servers ip address multiple nics powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, ping

I manage a large amount of servers and we have it set up where you can ping by servername (DNS records).Some of my servers have mulitple nics as well. So what I need is a script that I can ping mulitple servers and it will come back with the ip address of each nic for that server.If it can be exported to a csv that would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
function PingServer($serverName)
{
   (Test-Connection $serverName -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
}

$servers = "server1.com", "server2.com", "server3.com"

$hash = @{}
foreach($server in $servers)
{
   $hash.Add($server, (PingServer $server))
}
$hash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { New-Object PSObject -Property @{ ServerName = $_.Key; IPAddress = $_.Value } | Select-Object -Property ServerName, IPAddress } | Export-CSV -Path c:\PST\1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You might need to change it a bit for multiple network interfaces

Comment: ok thanks do i need the .com after each server name? Also which part identifies the NIC?

Comment: @BigCAT41 It's not that easy to track different NICs as when you ping it - it send response from the single address, not sure how you can do it. Try to play with 
`(Test-Connection $serverName -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString `

Comment: ok thanks. all i really need to worry about is the different ip addresses thats why I need all of the nics tracked.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this works for me, and I use it to retrieve all IPv4 addresses from a server. Bear in mind this tests it can ping it first before trying to get the info back, and uses WMI to get the data it needs.

```
#Get NIC IP Addresses
Function Get-NICIPAddresses
{
    param
    (
        $ComputerName
    )

    Try
    {
        $NICIPInformation = gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorAction "Stop"
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host "$($_.exception)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        return $Null
    }

    return $NICIPInformation
}

$Computer = "127.0.0.1"

if (Test-Connection -Quiet $Computer)
{
    #WMI IP Addresses
    [array]$IPInformation = Get-NICIPAddresses $Computer

    #IP Addresses
    if ($IPInformation.Count -gt 0)
    {
        #Array to hold all IP Addresses
        [array]$IPAddresses = @()

        #Loop through the IP Addresses, look for all IP addresses that match the AddressFamily "InterNetwork" - AKA IPv4 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.addressfamily.aspx
        foreach ($IPAddressInformation in $IPInformation)
        {
            #Use System.Net.IPAddress array to match the IP address values to acutal IP Addresses
            $IPAddresses += [System.Net.IPAddress[]]$IPAddressInformation.IPAddress | ? {$_.AddressFamily -eq "InterNetwork"}
        }

        #Sort the values from smallest to largest IP addresses
        $IPAddresses = $IPAddresses | % {$_.IPAddressToString} | Sort {"{0:d3}.{1:d3}.{2:d3}.{3:d3}" -f @([int[]]$_.split("."))}

        #Return string results, or $Null depending upon input.
        if ($IPAddresses.Count -gt 0)
        {
            $IPAddresses = $IPAddresses -Join " ; "
        }
        else
        {
            $IPAddresses = $Null
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $IPAddresses = $Null
    }

    #Return NIC info
    foreach ($NIC in $IPInformation)
    {
        $NIC
    }

    #Current IPv4 Addresses
    $IPAddresses
}
```